# Junit test fail on maven clean install - load a file in test resources folder

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit

I have a project that has a resource file in test folder:

- src/test/resources/myfolder/testfile.txt

I have:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String args[] = { "myfolder/testfile.txt" };
    MyClass.load(args);
}
```

And this is MyClass.java method:

```
public void load(String filePath)
            ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            //...
}
```

If I launch the tests from Eclipse, all the tests goes well.

I I launch the maven clean install, test fails with `java.lang.NullPointerException` at this line:

```
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

What I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `testfile.txt` resource is in the right place. This should work unless you have custom Maven resource filtering rules e.g. to exclude `.txt` files. Check what's in the `target/test-classes` after the failed build.

You could try to use absolute resource path `/myfolder/testfile.txt` instead and stop using `ContextClassLoader`:

```
String path = "/myfolder/testfile.txt";
InputStream inputStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the below line with the build tag in pom.xml.

```
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a same code for the same and its working for me. Please find below code, this might help you.

my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.radhey</groupId>
    <artifactId>junitTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Main class

```
public class TestJunit {
    public void load(String filePath)  {
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        String strCurrentLine;
        try {
            while ((strCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and Test class

```
public class Test {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        String args[] = { "test/testfile.txt" };
        TestJunit test2 = new TestJunit();
        test2.load(args[0]);
    }
}
```

I have also added this code to git

https://github.com/itthought/junitTest